# Implementing memory barriers in a threadpool?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, rust

Assume we have a very simple threadpool model.

The only operations it allows are adding tasks and running them (but tasks can add new tasks).

Let's say you want to synchronise the tasks. i.e. when adding a task you want to specify "this task cannot be run by a thread until that other task over there is fully consumed".

I have one idea that I think works but I suspect it's going to be very sub optimal.

- Add initial set of tasks and string identifiers (one per task) + blocking identifier for the task.
- Store the tasks in a map, using the identifier as the key.
- Spawn the work threads.
- Look at the first item in the map, then see if the blocking key is in the map, if it  is move to the next, otherwise remove the task from the map and execute it.

I am almost sure this works, but you are borderline single threading your application, each thread must lock the entire map and then iterate over every element in the map until it finds one that isn't blocked.

I am sure someone out there solved this already more elegantly.

This is the implementation I have atm without the barriers:

```rs
pub struct TaskMessage<'a>
{
    pub more_tasks: Vec<Task<'a>>,
    pub should_repeat: bool,
}

pub struct TaskList<'a>
{
    tasks: VecDeque<Task<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> TaskList<'a>
{
    pub fn push_task<F>(&mut self, task: F)
    where
        F: for<'b> FnMut(&'b mut TaskMessage<'a>) + Send + 'a,
    {
        self.tasks.push_back(Task(Box::new(task)));
    }

    fn pop_task(&mut self) -> Option<Task<'a>> { self.tasks.pop_front() }
}

pub struct ThreadPool<'a>
{
    task_list: Arc<Mutex<TaskList<'a>>>,
    max_threads: usize,
}

fn ceil_div(a: usize, b: usize) -> usize { (a / b) + ((a % b) != 0) as usize }

impl<'a> ThreadPool<'a>
{
    pub fn new<'b>() -> Self
    {
        let thread_count = thread::available_parallelism().unwrap().get();
        ThreadPool {
            task_list: Arc::new(Mutex::new(TaskList {
                tasks: VecDeque::new(),
            })),
            max_threads: thread_count,
        }
    }

    pub fn add_task<T>(&mut self, task: T)
    where
        T: for<'b> FnMut(&'b mut TaskMessage<'a>) -> () + Send + 'a,
    {
        self.task_list.lock().unwrap().push_task(task);
    }

    pub fn add_tasks<F: 'a, D: 'a>(&mut self, task: F, data: &'a mut [D])
    where
        F: Clone + for<'b> FnMut(&'b mut D, &'b mut TaskMessage<'a>) + Send + 'a,
        D: Send + Sync + std::fmt::Debug,
    {
        let num_chunks = ceil_div(data.len(), self.max_threads);
        let chunk_size = ceil_div(data.len(), num_chunks);

        for chunk in data.chunks_mut(chunk_size)
        {
            let mut task = task.clone();

            self.task_list.lock().unwrap().push_task(
                move |proxy: &mut TaskMessage<'a>| {
                    for item in chunk.iter_mut()
                    {
                        task(item, proxy)
                    }
                },
            );
        }
    }

    pub fn run(&mut self)
    {
        thread::scope(|s| {
            for _ in 0..self.max_threads
            {
                let task_clone = Arc::clone(&self.task_list);

                s.spawn(move || {
                    loop
                    {
                        let top_task = task_clone.lock().unwrap().pop_task();

                        if top_task.is_none()
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        let mut proxy = TaskMessage {
                            more_tasks: Vec::new(),
                            should_repeat: false,
                        };

                        let mut top_task = top_task.unwrap();

                        top_task.0(&mut proxy);

                        for task in proxy.more_tasks
                        {
                            task_clone.lock().unwrap().push_task(task.0);
                        }

                        if proxy.should_repeat
                        {
                            task_clone.lock().unwrap().push_task(top_task.0);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a priority queue job.

Comment: @Netwave how do you establish the priority when you don't have numbers, just a direct dependency of this node must be reached before that one?

Comment: You stablish a range of dependencies values (depending on how deep the dep graph/tree could be. You could use the three depth or some graph metric). Then you increase or decrease the value depending on the parent tasks and what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I have not compiled the code below.*

##### You don't pay for what you don't use

A good principle to uphold, when designing an algorithm -- or a data-structure -- is to aim for NOT having to use heavy-weight operations when NOT required.

Keeping this principle in mind helps you drive the algorithm design.

##### Task Dependencies

Applying the above principle, we can see some guidelines emerge:

1. A task with no upstream tasks should execute immediately.
2. A task with no downstream tasks should terminate immediately.

This suggests that it would be advantageous to keep dependencies *localized* to the tasks themselves:

1. A task should track which tasks it depends on, and wait for them to complete.
2. A task should track which tasks depends on it, and notify them when it's complete.

Localization is also good to avoid *contention*, by eliminating global data-structures:

1. No global map of dependencies.
2. No global map of ID to task, but instead *handles* to created tasks allowing interaction with them.

The idea, then, is that a task *waiting* on upstream tasks to complete will *not* be registered in the thread pool. Instead, it will be registered in each of the upstream tasks it's waiting on, and the last upstream dependency to complete will submit.

From there, we can sketch out the data:

```rust
/// Handle to a task.
///
/// Allows registering another task as a dependency.
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct TaskHandle(Arc<TaskDownstream>);

//
//  Implementation
//
struct Task {
    downstream: Arc<TaskDownstream>,
    task: Box<dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static>,
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct TaskDownstream {
    //  The count of upstream dependencies a task is waiting for, is the count of
    //  owners of the `Arc<Task>`.
    downstream: Mutex<Vec<Arc<Task>>>,
    completed: AtomicBool,
}
```

A task can be created without or with dependencies:

```rust
impl TaskHandle {
    /// Creates a task with no dependency.
    pub fn spawn<F>(pool: &ThreadPool, task: F) -> TaskHandle
    where
        F: FnOnce() + Send + 'static,
    {
        let downstream = Arc::default();
        let task = Box::new(task);

        let handle = TaskHandle(downstream.clone());

        pool.submit_task(Task { downstream, task });

        handle
    }

    /// Creates a task with dependencies.
    ///
    /// By construction, no circle of dependencies can be created.
    pub fn spawn_after<F, U>(pool: &ThreadPool, task: F, upstream: U) -> TaskHandle
    where
        F: FnOnce() + Send + 'static,
        U: IntoIterator<Item = TaskHandle>,
    {
        let downstream = Arc::default();
        let task = Box::new(task);

        let handle = TaskHandle(downstream.clone());
        let task = Arc::new(Task { downstream, task });

        for up in upstream {
            //  If already completed, no need to add it.
            if up.completed.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
                continue;
            }

            let mut downstream = up.completed.lock().expect("not poisoned");

            //  Race condition: may have completed in the meantime.
            if up.completed.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
                continue;
            }

            downstream.push(task.clone());
        }

        //  Now registered with all upstream dependencies,
        //  _but_ they may have completed in the meantime!
        if let Some(task) = Arc::into_inner(task) {
            pool.submit_task(task);
        }

        handle
    }
}
```

*You may also want to add a way to execute task which cannot be depended upon, skipping the allocation of `downstream`.*

And when a task complete, it should trigger the downstream tasks... if all their upstream dependencies have completed:

```rust
impl Task {
    fn run(self, pool: &ThreadPool) {
        let Task { downstream, task } = task;

        //  TODO: handle panicking, by flagging dependent tasks.
        task();

        downstream.completed.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);

        downstream
            .downstream
            .lock()
            .drain(..)
            //  Arc::into_inner returns the task if ready, None otherwise.
            .filter_map(Arc::into_inner)
            .for_each(|task| pool.submit_task(task));
    }
}
```

##### Design Notes

The whole system is fairly independent of the `ThreadPool` -- a good sign, design-wise -- and could be made even more independent if a `SubmitTask` trait existed, which could be implemented by various executors.

This is a *push* oriented system, by opposition to the *pull* nature of `Future`. This is more lightweight, but at the same time somewhat incompatible with the `async` ecosystem. Integrating it with the `async` ecosystem would require using `Waker`, etc... and I lack experience in implementing those, so preferred keeping it simple.

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't mix this dependency handling into the thread pool implementation.

Waiting for the thing it depends on should be part of the definition of the task:

- Creating a task should use `async` and return a `Future`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.async.html
- When a task needs to wait for another task, it should get that task's future and call `await!`
- Run your tasks with a standard [Threadpool](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/executor/struct.ThreadPool.html).  Just create them and [spawn](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/executor/struct.ThreadPool.html#method.spawn_ok) them.

Comment: There is no way you can achieve this without involving the thread pool to some extent is there? I want to implement a threadpool myself so I am not going to use the futures library.

If task A is waiting on Task B and the threadpool is in charge of scheduling which task to consume next, it needs to check wether B can be executed or not. How would you synchronize without the threadpool checking?

Comment: It actually works the same way as the other answer, except it's all handled by the standard library.  Only tasks that are ready to run are scheduled in the threadpool.  When a future completes, any tasks that were waiting for it become ready to run and are scheduled.